# Is there a way to automatically share Google Photos of someone in real time?

Tags: photos, google-photos

I take a lot of pictures of one person and this person always wants me to share them. Google Photos is really good at identifying these pictures and so I was wondering if there was a way that Google Photos could share these photos with them "in real time" i.e. some way that when I took a new photo of this person they would automatically be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing this can be achieved is by [**creating an auto-updating shared album**](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6131416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid).

> #### Create a shared album
>
> [steps omitted, see below]
>
> **Important:**
>
> - You can share directly to anyone with a Google Account if they're in your contacts or by search using their email address or phone number. For everyone else, you can [create a link to share](https://support.google.com/families/answer/6131416?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#send_linkandroid).
> - When you share a link to your album, anyone with the link can view the photos and add to the album. [Learn how sharing controls give your photos more privacy](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9789702).
> - If you share an album that automatically adds photos of face groups, anyone with access to the album can view photos as they're added.

There are multiple ways to set up:

1. Choose:

   - From the **Search** tab, select the **person**, then tap **Share as album**.
   - From the **Sharing** tab, tap **Create shared album**, choose **Select people & pets**, select the person, tap **Confirm** in the top-right corner.
2. Input the **album title**
3. Tap **Share** in the top-right corner, then tap **OK** on the confirmation dialog
4. Choose:

   - Select the Google Account of the one you want to share, then tap **Send**
   - Select an app, confirm **Create link**, then proceed to share the link from the app.